# When to create an application for Skype for Business

Tags: skype-for-business, ucwa

I am writing an iOS app that will use data from Skype for Business, and am following the guide from Microsoft called [Create an application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/createanapplication), which must be done before being able to use the API's.

What is unclear to me is when exactly to *create an application*? Is it:

- per client, i.e. only once ever?
- per home server?
- per user?
- per session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application here is more a kind of "virtual object (the application)"
 which needs to be created here, until you can start using Skype for Business (SfB) features.

So your question isn´t that easy to answer as its not clear what you wish to perform (e.g. did you wish to login, perform some task and then logoff again?). So it depends a little bit on your application and which features you are using. Therefore its no "only once ever" as the "virtual object (the application)" is destroyed at some time (e.g. your application crash and the SfB server no longer got a "yes we are still here and are listening" requests). This is controlled by the [lifetime of a token which is eight (8) hours for authenticated users](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/authenticationinucwa) so you need to renew that or your application will stop working. So its more a "per taskuser & login & time" approach...

Microsoft explained the above as well in the following [statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/ucwa/createanapplication): "This is how you register your application with UCWA 2.0 as an agent of the user whose credentials you obtained in a previous step."

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I had just finished registering an application for the MS graph API, which only needs to be done once. That definitely contributed to the confusion.

Comment: Videre, it sounds like you are confusing two entirely different "application" concepts.  Application *registration* for MS graph API involves using the Azure Application Portal to create a client id, permissions, and redirect url. In that case, you are *registering* an application that you have written. You only register it once to get a client id and redirect url into your iOS app, and then make REST or client library (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ios) calls from the client app.  In this case, the actual application is a program

Comment: continuing previous comment...

The Skype for Business Trusted Application API docs that you linked to initially refer to a different kind of application creation.  In the case of the Trusted Application API, you're actually creating a real live client object at run-time that can sent and receive REST calls from the Trusted Application API endpoint. In that case, you do need to create the application every time you start the service.
I will add a para in the Trusted App API topic that explains the difference between Azure app registration and Trusted App API application creation.

Comment: I actually didn't link to the Trusted Application API, I linked to the UCWA API

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an iOS application that will interact with a Skype for Business server, you can use the [Skype for Business App SDK for iOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/appsdk/skypeappsdk). This client library handles anonymous meeting joins for users who are not homed on a Skype for Business server. 
For all other Skype for Business features, you'll need to use an iOS REST library of your choice. The REST endpoint that works best for a client application is actually the [Skype Web SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/skypewebsdk). The Skype [Trusted Application API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/trusted-application-api/docs/overview) is designed for server-to-server communications where your server is talking to a Skype for Business Online instance. In that case, your server obtains and processes Skype data and then it makes it available to a client such as an iOS app.  
Unless you intend to create a middle tier between Skype for Business Online and your iOS app, you should use the Web SDK.

Comment: I need to use the UCWA API, none of the other options solve my problem.